# How do I Quit IRB from the command line? (Using terminal on mac)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, terminal, irb

Basically, I'm typing along just fine in terminal, using IRB to run ruby commands:

```
2.0.0-p0 :014 > bank_account.withdraw(2222)
 => -1222
```

But sometimes I accidentally miss out a quotation mark.

```
2.0.0-p0 :020 > BankAccount.create_for("Jim","Johnson)
2.0.0-p0 :021"> bank_account.withdraw(333)
```

If you look carefully, you'll see that the speech mark I missed out appears next to the line number on the left, next to the patch version.

From here on in, that speech mark appears everytime I run a command! And it stops the commands working:

```
2.0.0-p0 :021"> BankAccount.create_for("Julian","Hurley")
2.0.0-p0 :022"> BankAccount.create_for("Katt","Smith")
2.0.0-p0 :023"> exec($0)
```

What I want to know is, how do I get rid of that quotation mark? Or quit IRB from the command line in order to reset it?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you haven't closed a quote, just put a quote in and hit return.

Exiting from the console can be done by typing exit, though in the circumstance your are would need to hit Control - C

Comment: and if you made the mistake twice? ie did `puts 'hi` and then again `puts 'hi`.

Comment: That will cause an error because when it his the second `'` it will close the string and then try to evaluate `hi` as a keyword

Answer (score 18):

Control - C followed by Control - Z. 
I hope it helps!

Comment: Pretty sure C-z just puts the process in the background instead of terminating it. You can type `jobs` to verify and then `fg 1` (or whatever job number) to resume the process

Answer (score 17):

I was having the same problem. To exit `irb` within the terminal, type `exit`.

Answer (score 7):

Use **Ctrl-D**, it is an end-of-input for irb. If you are in the middle of some command, use Ctrl-C first to terminate the input of this command.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in the middle of a multi-line block (according to the interpreter), hit Ctrl+C to break out of it.

Then you can do any of the following to quit:

- `exit` (or `exit()`)
- `quit` (or `quit()`)
- `irb_exit` (or `irb_exit()`)
- Ctrl+D (sends the `EOF` character)